# Problems in saving records in database in service tier with data which comes from rabbit mq consumer in grails 4.0.3

Tags: grails, rabbitmq

**I am in trouble using RabbitMQ queues with Grails 4.0.3. and JVM Version: 1.8.0_275**

I don't knwow why but I have a rabbit consumer whcih has to do some stuff and, among them, save data in the database, as below.

```
package br.gov.cmb.pid.consumers

import br.gov.cmb.pid.domain.RenachLog
import br.gov.cmb.pid.services.PidService
import com.budjb.rabbitmq.consumer.MessageContext
import com.budjb.rabbitmq.publisher.RabbitMessagePublisher
import grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional
import org.grails.web.json.JSONObject

@Transactional
class PidIssuingConsumer {
    RabbitMessagePublisher rabbitMessagePublisher
    static rabbitConfig = [ queue : "detran.transactions.191.requests" ]
    JSONObject icomResp

    def handleMessage(Map body, MessageContext messageContext) {
        icomResp = new JSONObject().accumulate("status","No response available")
        PidService pidService

        try {
            icomResp = sendPidIssuingToIcom(body as JSONObject)
            publishIcomPidIssuingResponse(icomResp)
            saveRenachLog(icomResp.toString())
        } catch (Exception e){
            saveRenachLog(e.getLocalizedMessage())
            println(e.printStackTrace())
        }
    }

    def sendPidIssuingToIcom(JSONObject pidIssuingDocument){
        println(pidIssuingDocument)
        return pidIssuingDocument
    }

    def publishIcomPidIssuingResponse(JSONObject pidIssuingResponse){
        rabbitMessagePublisher.send {
            exchange = "detran.requests"
            routingKey = "191-response"
            body = [response: pidIssuingResponse]
        }
        println(pidIssuingResponse)
    }

    def saveRenachLog(String icomResp){
        RenachLog renachLog = new RenachLog()
        renachLog.transactionId = "191"
        renachLog.loggedOn = new Date()
        renachLog.logDescription = icomResp
        renachLog.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
    }
}
```

This code works as expected, but it is my desire that the methods saveRenachLog and sendPidIssuingToIcom to be separated in my service PidService.groovy. Unfortunately, when I do that, I receive this exception message below.

Localized message:

Complete Stack Trace.
2021-11-03 12:06:52.399 ERROR --- [pool-5-thread-1] c.b.r.consumer.AbstractConsumerContext   : unhandled exception java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException caught in RabbitMQ message handler for consumer br.gov.cmb.pid.consumers.PidIssuingConsumer

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.budjb.rabbitmq.consumer.LegacyConsumerContext.process(LegacyConsumerContext.groovy:262)
        at com.budjb.rabbitmq.consumer.LegacyConsumerContext$process.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:156)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:168)
        at com.budjb.rabbitmq.consumer.AbstractConsumerContext.deliverMessage(AbstractConsumerContext.groovy:325)
        at com.budjb.rabbitmq.consumer.ConsumerContext$deliverMessage.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:127)
        at com.budjb.rabbitmq.consumer.RabbitMessageHandler.handleDelivery(RabbitMessageHandler.groovy:100)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerDispatcher$5.run(ConsumerDispatcher.java:149)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerWorkService$WorkPoolRunnable.run(ConsumerWorkService.java:104)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method saveRenachLog() on null object
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:43)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:34)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:127)
        at br.gov.cmb.pid.consumers.PidIssuingConsumer.$tt__handleMessage(PidIssuingConsumer.groovy:25)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:1011)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:994)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethodSafe(InvokerHelper.java:97)
        at br.gov.cmb.pid.consumers.PidIssuingConsumer$_handleMessage_closure1.doCall(PidIssuingConsumer.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:263)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:421)
        at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:94)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
        at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:91)
        at br.gov.cmb.pid.consumers.PidIssuingConsumer.handleMessage(PidIssuingConsumer.groovy)
        ... 20 common frames omitted
```

**I have already inserted @Transactional in my service code.**

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note 1: I can't tell what the code looks like when you moved the methods to the service, you might want to include the code that fails.

That said, it looks like you're declaring your pidService inside your method, with a default value of null, then trying to call methods on it.

try changing this:

```
RabbitMessagePublisher rabbitMessagePublisher
static rabbitConfig = [ queue : "detran.transactions.191.requests" ]
JSONObject icomResp

def handleMessage(Map body, MessageContext messageContext) {
    icomResp = new JSONObject().accumulate("status","No response available")
    PidService pidService
```

to this:

```
RabbitMessagePublisher rabbitMessagePublisher
PidService pidService
static rabbitConfig = [ queue : "detran.transactions.191.requests" ]
JSONObject icomResp

def handleMessage(Map body, MessageContext messageContext) {
    icomResp = new JSONObject().accumulate("status","No response available")
```

Note pidService is now a class property, not a method-local variable.  If PidService is another service in Grails, then it should inject normally and be usable.  At the least this should clear out your NullPointerException, and let you move on in your debugging.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It is now working fine.